# Similar function of ArcGIS Network Analyst in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, network-analyst

I am currently using MapInfo and trying to create a road network base walking catchment map, rather than just a cycle buffer. The finished plan should look similar as follows.

[image]

This map was created in ArcGIS with the Network Analyst feature. I wonder whether MapInfo has the similar feature to generate this kind of map? maybe in the latest version v12.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pitney Bowes offers a similar product.  It's called [DriveTime](http://www.pbinsight.com.au/support/product-documentation/details/drivetime) (another link [here](http://www.pbinsight.co.in/products/location-intelligence/applications/mapping-analytical/mapinfo-drivetime/)) and it's an additional program which you can buy.  It's not built into MapInfo, unfortunately.

I've always had Pitney Bowes run the drive times for me.  I've never been terribly impressed with the results, but they did the job.  They were able to provide catchment polygons, like in your image, as well as a line file which contained routes and times between all the points to all other points.

I'm not sure if you have to purchase Pitney Bowes road data for it to work.  Have a look here: http://www.mapinfo.com/data-products/drivetime-routing/

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use your own network in Drivetime, but you have to crunch some binary files and it is quite fussy in regards to topological consistency.

Works well once it's all set up though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new tool available, too. Well new in the Pitney Bowes product range. The tool is called MapInfo RouteFinder.

You can see a demo on how to creating catchment area like the ones above here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NZDK4R2ZWw.

You can read a bit more about the product in this article from the MapInfo Journal:
http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-nov-2014/MapInfo-RouteFinder-Using-Isochrones

MapInfo RouteFinder can create networks from tab files holding basic information for routing.

Pitney Bowes also sell networks based on the TomTom road network, including travel speed at morning rush hour, evening rush hour, between rush hours and during the weekend.

You might have heard about RouteFinder before. RouteFinder for MapInfo is a tool developed by RouteWare. Pitney Bowes has entered into an agreement with RouteWare to create our own "MapInfo RouteFinder" version of their product.